# The title on 2 lines in CSS

Tags: css

For aesthetic reasons, I would like a title to take up the maximum of the available space, but on 2 lines. I would like to use CSS only. Here is my code:

```css
.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 4vw;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br> consectetur adipiscing elit
</h1>
```

It works a bit, but I think there are better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use
`max-width` paired with `white-space`

```css
.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 4vw;
  max-width: 30ch;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example...

```css
.parent {
    width: 300px;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block-ellipsis {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <h2>Single Line Ellipsis</h2>
    <div class="ellipsis">
        This is an example of an ellipsis. once we reach 300px of length then the text will be cut off.
    </div>
    <h2>Multiple Line Ellipsis</h2>
    <div class="block-ellipsis">
        This is an example of a multi-line ellipsis. We just set the number of lines we want to display before the ellipsis takes into effect and make some changes to the CSS and the ellipsis should take into effect once we reach the number of lines we want.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your alternative can be very interesting for example a blog home page that lists all the articles. It doesn't solve my current concern, because I need to read the entire title; but I keep your solution for the blog home page. Thank you.